# React Router v4 throw PropTypes error when using withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to setup a project using React router v4, which i managed to made it work just fine.

However, when I try to implement the function to scroll back to the top, [according to this docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/scroll-restoration), there is this error:

> Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

I already downloaded the React `prop-types` package. This error only appears if I set withRouter() within the component, for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class ScrollTop extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if ( this.props.location !== prevProps.location ) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollTop);
```

The code above will generate the error. But if I use the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class ScrollTop extends Component {
    // ..same as code above..
}

export default ScrollTop;
```

This doesn't present the error, but also doesn't scroll back to the top when changing routes.

How can I solve this proble? Or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React 15.5.0 added this deprecation warning](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.proptypes). Even though you are importing PropTypes from its new location, the latest release react router v4 is not. A [PR for it](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4937) has already been merged, but has not yet been released.

Your options are to wait for react-router to publish the release (I would expect that should be pretty soon), install react-router from master, or downgrade React to 15.4.0 temporarily.